# Adding ArcGIS MapServer Layer via Python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, arcgis-rest-api

I'm trying to add an ArcGIS MapServer layer from python code. The code I am running (currently via the console to test) is:

```
data = QgsDataSourceURI()
data.setParam("url", "http://egis.fire.ca.gov/arcgis/rest/services/FRAP/DE_HHZTier2/MapServer")
data.setParam("layer", "0")

iface.addRasterLayer(str(data.encodedUri()), "mylayer", "arcgismapserver")
```

This results in the error:

```
Invalid Layer: AMSProvider Could not parse spatial reference Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: arcgismapserver, URI: layer=0&url=http://egis.fire.ca.gov/arcgis/rest/services/FRAP/DE_HHZTier2/MapServer
```

Adding the same service/layer via the UI (Layer -> Add Layer -> Add ArcGIS MapServer Layer) works great.

Answer (score 3):

Sorted it out, the data source uri needs to be space delimited. So changing it to:

```
iface.addRasterLayer("url='http://.../MapServer' layer='0'", "mylayer", "arcgismapserver")
```

Does the trick.